# Jasper server integration in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to configure jasperserver-client gem in order to receive reports from Jasper server through SOAP.

The error I get is **JasperServer::Error: JasperServer replied with an error: exception getting data strategy**
after running the following from console:

client = JasperServer::Client.new("http://example.com/jasperserver-pro/services/repository", "jasperadmin", "jasperadmin")

request = JasperServer::ReportRequest.new("/public/test2", "PDF", { 'last_login_at' => '2013-01-15 00:00:00'})

pdf_data = client.request_report(request)

Any idea what might be the cause. I think that it's able to find the server and the report but it might be something wrong with the optional parameters.

I also tried generating the request without the option hash

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with this tutorial
http://jonif.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/